# Let's remove the "change" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[change](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/change) is an absolutely meaningless tag.

With 43 questions tagged, it should be easy to get rid of. All that's needed is a handful of users who want to go through these questions and remove the tag, while also fixing other issues such as bad grammar or spelling, and flagging questions that are otherwise inappropriate.

'sup community, can we do this?

<sub><sub>Yes we can!</sub></sub>

Comment: I edited four (holding off on more to avoid flooding.) Interestingly enough, several of the questions have *other* superfluous tags. This could lead to a larger cleanup than just 43 questions.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gXsAlEt.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

… aaaaand it's gone.